# iBatis create an array of multiple annotations (annotation reuse)

Tags: java, ibatis

My greetings!

I am pretty new to `iBatis` and I have faced such kind of optimization problem: I have two absolutely identical `@Results` with just 1 parameter in difference. Is there any way I could create some sort of annotation-array to reuse it for mapping? The source looks like that:

```
public static interface StoreMapper {
   @Select("SELECT * FROM STORE WHERE STORE_NUMBER = #{storeNumber}")
   @Results(value = {
      @Result(property="storeNumber", column="STORE_NUMBER"),
      @Result(property="districtId", column="DISTRICT_ID"),
      @Result(property="managerName", column="MANAGER_NAME")})
   Store findByStoreNumber (Integer storeNumber) throws FacadeException;

   @Select("SELECT * FROM STORE WHERE STATE = #{state}")
   @Results(value = {
      @Result(property="storeNumber", column="STORE_NUMBER"),
      @Result(property="districtId", column="DISTRICT_ID"),
      @Result(property="managerName", column="MANAGER_NAME")})
   List<Store> findByState (String state) throws FacadeException;
}
```

I read, that I could use XML, but is there a way to do it with annotation usage? They are pretty handy.