# How to DRY when using Swagger UI and the ApiResponses annotations with Java Spring endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I like `Swagger` because it makes your apis very user friendly. I use `Swagger` annotations like

- @ApiParam
- @ApiResponse | @ApiResponses
- @ApiOperation
- Others

On endpoints, query params, request params, request body and so on.

I like to keep my `POJO` classes clean and in general I try my best to follow `DRY` rule however, when it comes to swagger I noticed that I keep **repeating** myself over and over as shown below

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve object by id")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "ISE")
})
public Response retrieveById(@ApiParam(value = "Some id") @PathParam("sid") int id) {       
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Create object")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "ISE")
})
public Response create(@ApiParam(value = "Request body") RequestBody body) {
}
```

How to avoid repeating yourself with `Swagger annotations`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I did some Googling around and came across this [github issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/690) and some other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045751/combine-multiple-annotations-into-one-to-avoid-repeating-them) that are not directly related to `ApiResponses` annotations and none of them seem to present a working solution.

Using `Swagger UI 2.0`  I thought let's give it a try, so I did the following

1. I created a custom annotations `GroupedApiResponses..`
2. I annotated `GroupedApiResponses..` with a group of Swagger annotations
3. I used the `GroupedApiResponses..` annotations on top of endpoints
4. Works just like before

See below

```
package com.raf.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ok"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "ISE") 
})
public @interface GroupedApiResponsesAvecOk {
}
```

Similarly (you can group annotations as you want in one or more than one custom annotation depending on structure of your endpoints and the response messages it return)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "ISE") 
})
public @interface GroupedApiResponsesAvecCreated {
}
```

And then I used the above `@GroupedApiResponsesAvecOk` on `retrieveById` and `@GroupedApiResponsesAvecCreated` on `create` endpoint in place of `@ApiResponses` and worked it just like before.

As shown above, the `ApiResponse` annotations relating to `400, 404, 500` can now be reused across other endpoints.

Comment: Very nice. Is there anyway to provide an input to the new meta-annotation that allows the user to specify the response type for one of the @ApiResponses?